# Pull notification methods

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I want to design a notification component. I want to understand what type of pulling notification methods are used out there to effectively pull the notification with minimal stress on the server.

Let's say for example I want to notify user of a chat message, I imagine I would need to pull the data quite regularly, like every 500ms for a quick response. However, doing this may overload the system. Hypothetically speaking if I have a million user browsing the site that's 2 million requests every second!

I'm thinking of writing an algorithm that will incrementally increase the pull interval by 1 second on each pull up to a maximum of 60 second. The interval will reset to 500ms if there is new data. In this way, if the user has frequent notification it will be instant. But if there hasn't been notification for a longer period of time, there maybe a bit of delay of up to a minute.

In essence I'm compromising between user experience and server load to find a middle ground for both.

Please advise on possible drawback of this approach if any. Is there a proper name for it?

Alternatively, is there a better method out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is pulling or long pulling. Effectively it is not good for performance.

The alternative way is pushing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). You push the data when there is something new.
you could use web socket it achieve this.

You could look at Apollo messaging middle-ware that have native support for websockets and good performances.
http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/

Comment: Thanks. I know of long polling, push technology and socket. However, the drawback would be the limits on how many connection you can keep open at any one given time. My method won't hold the connection open, it goes to sleep incrementally.

Comment: So you are looking for a better algorithm/method ?

Comment: Well, I guess the question is how do larger projects work around the limitations presented with both the long polling and socket method? Is it a matter of adding more servers to handle more requests?

Answer (score -1):

The method you are using could lead a network traffic overload on your server if there are many clients connected . Let's suppose you have 1000 clients connected : the server will have to handle 1000 different connections. A better approach is using a push notification system. Check this out https://nodejs.org/it/docs/